# rigid body bake - how to make a long rigid body animation?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cache

So i made a little longer animation (> 1000 frames) with a bit more complicated rigid body physics (a vehicle driving around).
All went well, but...
after frame 500 it got really annoying that i have to start the rb simulation always at frame 0 to see what's really going on, because if you start in the "middle" in won't be the same as if you start at frame 0.
AFAIK you can only bake all, but not in "substeps" (e.g. bake only frame 1-100, then change rb settings from 101-200 and then bake 101-200) ...so...
how do you guys solve this problem so that you can have one single cam shot of that?
Or do you make clever "cuts" where the camera show something else and then you start a new rigid body simulation?

...and tbh i would never have the patience to even start a 10000 frame rb sim....